# Getting Information about locks associated with a process

Tags: linux, process, lock

I am unable to list the locks associated with a process and information about the locks i.e How many threads share this lock etc.

Kindly tell my how to extract this information from a process ID.

My case:

I have run `sysbench` command

```
sysbench --test=threads --thread-locks=100 --max-time=20s run
```

I want to list locks that sysbench just created and information about the locks i.e which threads the sharing this lock etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about file locks,

```
lsof -p PID
```

will list all files opened by process with `PID`.

```
lsof -c processname
```

will list all files opened by `processname`.

Note that `lsof` lists also files opened only for read i.e. without file locks. The mode under which a file is open is specified as the fourth character in the FD (File Descriptor) column in the output:

```
                   r for read access;
                   w for write access;
                   u for read and write access;
                   space if mode unknown and no lock
                        character follows;
                   `-' if mode unknown and lock
                        character follows.
```

Comment: I have run sysbench  command

sysbench --test=threads --thread-locks=100 --max-time=20s run

Comment: now i want to list the locks that sysbench just created and find information about the locks i.e which threads are sharing these locks

Comment: Then please edit your question and add this information there.

Answer (score 0):

you can get lock process list using below command

```
lslocks
```

Comment: lslocks does not list the locks associated with a process in my case

I am running sysbench command

sysbench --test=threads --thread-locks=100 --max-time=20s run

Locks associated with sysbench are not listing in lslocks